# curl_multi_select always blocking for time out value

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

When running [Example #1 from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) on Windows XP PHP 5.3.5 the `curl_multi_select()` line will always block for the duration of the timeout specified (if blank it will block for 1 sec, if I specify 5 sec timeout it will block for 5 sec) regardless of the time it takes to get the content. I suspect it's related to [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60790).

The question is: what's the best work around? The best I can come up with is to get rid of `curl_multi_select()` and `usleep(x)` as a way to save some cycles.

Answer (score 3):

This might help as long as you can live with 1 second blocking.

There is a comment on the [manual page for `curl_multi_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) that mentions this blocking lasts until at least one connection has completed or `$timeout` seconds, whichever occurs first. They also write that calls to `curl_multi_select` should be wrapped:

```
private function full_curl_multi_exec($mh, &$still_running) {
        do {
                $rv = curl_multi_exec($mh, $still_running);
        } while ($rv == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        return $rv;
}
```

Then modify your loop that checks for running handles:

```
// execute the handles
$still_running = null;
$this->full_curl_multi_exec($mh, $still_running);

// check whether the handles have finished
do { // "wait for completion"-loop 
        curl_multi_select($mh); // non-busy (!) wait for state change 
        $this->full_curl_multi_exec($mh, $still_running); // get new state
        while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) { 
            // process completed request (e.g. curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle'])) 
        }
} while ($still_running);
```

Prior to this modification, code that was tested with PHP 5.4 was not working on an Amazon instance running PHP 5.3.20 due to [this bug in PHP 5.3.18](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63411), which causes calls to `curl_multi_select()` to never return anything other than `-1`

I am now able to retrieve data from nearly 1,300 URLs in less than 30 seconds using batches of 200 handles.